# Change XML node value when I have more than one TABLE tag

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to change a value in an XML file. Should be easy except even typing like a monkey I cannot get it to work. The XML snippet is below:

```
<SENDLABEL LABELACTION="PRINT" NAMEINPRINTER="MLabel1" PRINTERVARIANT="162-12L" FORMAT="LEGACY" PRINTTOFILEPATH="">

<TABLE NAME="PARAMVALUE"><ROWDATA><ROW PARAM="MAXGRAPHICCOMPRESSION" VALUE="0"/><ROW PARAM="BARCODELABELSEQNOLEN" VALUE="0"/><ROW PARAM="LABELROTATION" VALUE="0"/><ROW PARAM="BARCODEGLOBALSEQNOLEN" VALUE="0"/><ROW PARAM="PRINTAMOUNT" VALUE="1"/><ROW PARAM="LABELLOCATION" VALUE="0"/><ROW PARAM="CHARACTERMODE" VALUE="ASCII"/></ROWDATA></TABLE>

<TABLE NAME="PLSAREA"><ROWDATA><ROW PLSETUPNO="11217" PRINTERAREA="0"/></ROWDATA></TABLE>

<TABLE NAME="PLSCHAN"><ROWDATA><ROW PLSETUPNO="11217" PRINTERAREA="0" CHANNELINDEX="0" HORIZONTALDPI="304" VERTICALDPI="304" RASTER="0"/></ROWDATA></TABLE>

<TABLE NAME="PLSETUP"><ROWDATA><ROW LABELHEIGHT="795" LABELWIDTH="580,147"/></ROWDATA></TABLE>
```

The code I use is below. The PRINTERVARIANT will change no problem but the LABELHEIGHT will not. Maybe it is that the XML has many TABLE and somehow I need to specify this is the one with value PLSETUP? If so how do I do that please.

```
string variant = "108-12L";
string height = "378";
string width = "377,952";

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(name);
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/SENDLABEL");
node.Attributes["PRINTERVARIANT"].Value = variant;

XmlNode node2 = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/SENDLABEL/TABLE/ROWDATA/ROW");
node2.Attributes["LABELHEIGHT"].Value = height;
```

Comment: The code you have written will only update the value for the first row it encounters. You will have to loop through for the remaining rows. Use xmlDocument.SelectNodes and a foreach loop.

Comment: Xpath for the table with name "PLSETUP" is `"/SENDLABEL/TABLE[@NAME='PLSETUP']/ROWDATA/ROW"` (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieve in many ways, but Linq to xml is my preferred choice.

```
var rows = doc.Descendants("ROW")
              .Where(e=>  e.Attribute("LABELHEIGHT") != null);
```

Now you can update the rows with **LABELHEIGHT** by looping through the items (As need says)

```
rows.First().Attribute("LABELHEIGHT").Value = ""; // your value
```

and finally you can save the changes using

```
 doc.Save(); Save your changes.
```

Take look at the [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lSU1lx)